# Extract n characters for the first match of a word in a file

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python. I have a file having single line of data. My requirement is to extract "n" characters after certain words for their first occurrence only. Also, those words are not sequential.

Data file: `{"id":"1234566jnejnwfw","displayId":"1234566jne","author":{"name":"abcd@xyz.com","datetime":15636378484,"displayId":"23423426jne","datetime":4353453453}`

I want to fetch value after first match of "displayId" and before "author", i.e.; 1234566jne. Similarly for "datetime".

I tried breaking the line based upon index as the word and putting it into another file for further cleaning up to get the exact value.

```
tmpFile = "tmpFile.txt"
tmpFileOpen = open(tmpFile, "w+")

with open("data file") as openfile:
       for line in openfile:
           tmpFileOpen.write(line[line.index(displayId) + len(displayId):])
```

However, I am sure this is not a good solution to work further.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer should work for any displayId with a similar format as in your question. I decided not to load the JSON file for this answer, because it wasn't needed to accomplish the task.

```
import re

tmpFile = "tmpFile.txt"
tmpFileOpen = open(tmpFile, "w+")

with open('data_file.txt', 'r') as input:
  lines = input.read()

  # Use regex to find the displayId element
  # example: "displayId":"1234566jne
  # \W matches none words, such as " and :
  # \d matches digits
  # {6,8} matches digits lengths between 6 and 8
  # [a-z] matches lowercased ASCII characters
  # {3} matches 3 lowercased ASCII characters
  id_patterns = re.compile(r'\WdisplayId\W{3}\d{6,8}[a-z]{3}')
  id_results = re.findall(id_patterns, lines)

  # Use list comprehension to clean the results
  clean_results = ([s.strip('"displayId":"') for s in id_results])

  # loop through clean_results list
  for id in clean_results:
    # Write id to temp file on separate lines
    tmpFileOpen.write('{} \n'.format(id))

    # output in tmpFileOpen
    # 1234566jne 
    # 23423426jne
```

This answer does load the JSON file, but this answer will fail if the JSON file format changes.

```
import json

tmpFile = 'tmpFile.txt'
tmpFileOpen = open(tmpFile, "w+")

# Load the JSON file
jdata = json.loads(open('data_file.txt').read())

# Find the first ID
first_id = (jdata['displayId'])
# Write the first ID to the temp file
tmpFileOpen.write('{} \n'.format(first_id))

# Find the second ID
second_id = (jdata['author']['displayId'])
# Write the second ID to the temp file
tmpFileOpen.write('{} \n'.format(second_id))

# output in tmpFileOpen
# 1234566jne 
# 23423426jne
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer helped me and I am able to derive the solution as there was a change in json structure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you can achieve this by doing the following:

```
import json

tmpFile = "tmpFile.txt"
tmpFileOpen = open(tmpFile, "w+")

with open("data.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        // Loads the json to a dict in order to manipulate it easily
        data = json.loads(str(line))
        // Here I specify that I want to write to my tmp File only the first 3
        // characters of the field `displayId`
        tmpFileOpen.write(data['displayId'][:3])
```

This can be done because the data in your file is JSON, however if the format changes it won't work

Comment: Thank you, Milox. Your reply helped me too.